How to Disable Google Translate in Next.js to Prevent client side errors?
I’m facing an issue in my Next.js web app (Next.js 14, React 18). When the app loads, I encounter the following errors in the browser console:


After some investigation, I discovered that if I disable Google Translate, the error no longer occurs. However, I don’t want to manually ask users to disable Google Translate. I’m looking for a way to disable Google Translate programmatically or through configuration on my site to prevent this error from affecting my users.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far but those configurations are not working...

_document.ts

  <Html lang="en" translate="no">
      <Head>{emotionStyleTags}</Head>
      <body translate="no">
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>


next.config.js

  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/(.*)',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'X-Content-Type-Options',
            value: 'nosniff',
          },
          {
            key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
            value: "frame-ancestors 'self'",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },

Is there a way to configure my Next.js app to prevent Google Translate from interfering with my app’s functionality, specifically to avoid this IndexSizeError?
Is there a way to programmatically disable Google Translate for users who visit my site?

maybe am late but i have faced same problem today and the solution i got is
<body
        className={montserrat.className}
        translate="no"
      >
        {children}
      </body>

adding translate="no" works great
Also here is my full code in layout.jsx
import { Montserrat } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

const montserrat = Montserrat({
  weight: ["200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", "900"],
  subsets: ["cyrillic"],
});

export const metadata = {
  title: "",
  description: "",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="fr">
      <body
        className={montserrat.className}
        translate="no"
      >
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

